# How to check hashtable contains a correct class

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, hashtable

Does anyone knows how to check a class contains exactly the same value inside a hashtable? like a example code below, even if i set item1 and item2 same of the one in hashtable, it still return me a "not found" message.

```
public class WebService2 : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        public class Good
        {
            public string item1="address";
            public string item2 ="postcode";
        }

        [WebMethod]

        public string findhome()
        {

            Dictionary<Color, string> hash = new Dictionary<Color, string>();

            Good good = new Good();
            hash.Add(new Good() { item1 = "address", item2 = "postcode" },"home");

            if (hash.ContainsKey(good))
            {
                return (string)hash[good];
            }

            return "not supported";


        }
    }
```

Comment: It will do, first you check if hash contains `color`, this isn't mentioned anywhere. then you return `good` which is just a new good which has no relevance, and no idea how `Good` is a Color

Comment: First prepare a *compilable* code. That way your question can be more meaningfull.

Comment: @Sayse sorry, i forgot to replace color with good, edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Your question is still not clear. But i'll try to make a guess)* It is because your objects' *references* are compared. You should define the equality for your object. For example,

```
public class Good
{
    public string item1 = "address";
    public string item2 = "postcode";

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return (item1+item2).GetHashCode();
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (!(obj is Good)) return false;
        if (obj == null) return false;

        var good = obj as Good;
        return good.item1==item1 && good.item2==item2;
    }
}
```

*PS:* `As long as an object is used as a key in the Dictionary<TKey, TValue>, it must not change in any way that affects its hash value.` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx

Comment: After implement equals and hashtable, it works! thanks